# Javascript array transferring, but values are not

Tags: javascript

I have a function `quickbuy_view.checkout()`
which accepts a `product` object.
I call the function with

```
quickbuy_view.checkout(new Product(12530257))
```

This is part of the code where a bug arises

```
console.log('quickbuy_view')
console.log(quickbuy_view)
console.log('quickbuy_view.product')
console.log(quickbuy_view.product)
console.log('quickbuy_view.product.displays');
console.log(quickbuy_view.product.displays);

var display = quickbuy_view.product.displays[0];
//This is where the actual error occurs
$('#quickbuy .display .main img').attr('src',display.vw1Reg)
```

In chrome's console I can see that `quickbuy_view.product` returns an object with an `displays` array of length 3. However when I attempt to log `quickbuy_view.product.displays`, an empty array is returned.

The weird thing is, when I later enter `quickbuy_view.product.displays`, I get the array as expected.

[image: Console view]

Comment: This could be related to lazy evaluation of objects in the Chrome console. How is the array populated? If Ajax is involved, then your are probably accessing the array before it was filled with values.

Comment: Lazy evaluation was the issue, thanks! Why don't you answer below so you can the credit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the way Chrome Dev Tools `console.log` works. When you log an object it's still live, that is it's not a snapshop of it's present state. However, when you log a primitive it is the current state of the property.

So the `displays` array is being set after the code is being logged but when you inspect the `product` property it is "live" so it doesn't get updated until you expand it.